# How can I pass a comma seperated list of values within PowerShell as a parameter to a CmdLet using splatting with hash tables?

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, hashtable, powershell-cmdlet

I would like to use "splatting" with hash tables to pass variable parameters to a CmdLet. I want to modify the following command:

```
New-SmbShare -Name Share$ -Path C:\Folder -ChangeAccess MACHINE\User1
```

If I do this only for the `ChangeAccess` parameter , I end up with the following result:

```
$Args = @{ChangeAccess = 'MACHINE\User1'}
New-SmbShare -Name Share$ -Path C:\Folder @Args
```

This works very well.

The parameter `ChangeAcces` accepts a comma seperated list of users, so if I would like to give two users the change permission on the share, I would use the following command:

```
New-SmbShare -Name Share$ -Path C:\Folder -ChangeAccess MACHINE\User1,MACHINE\User2
```

If I replace this command the same way with splatting, I end up with this:

```
$Args = @{ChangeAccess = 'MACHINE\User1,MACHINE\User2'}
New-SmbShare -Name Share$ -Path C:\Folder @Args
```

Now the command fails with a "CimException". Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: `'MACHINE\User1','MACHINE\User2'`

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I marked @Chard's answer as the solution, because I could not mark your comment as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `-ChangeAccess <string[]>` accepts a string or an array of strings. This is why is was failing with `ChangeAccess = 'MACHINE\User1,MACHINE\User2'` It's seeing the whole string as one user, you will need to use the array option for multiple users:

```
$Args = @{ChangeAccess = 'MACHINE\User1','MACHINE\User2'}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charme! I need to look more in detail at the function description in the future! ;)